# Calculating rotation angle based on the applied transformation

Tags: matrices, rotations

I have got a quite complex problem. I have a particle simulation program, and i want to add solid objects to it, but still particle-based. for this, i want to deteermine the rotation the given transformation applies to my object. I have been trying to figure this out myself(couldnt find anything too much related to this)

heres what information i have:

- Old point coordinates
- New point coordinates
- Speed on X and Y axis
- Rotation center

I only need to calculate one points rotation angle(ill solve the rest) heres how far i got:

```
x' = x * cos( theta ) + y * -sin( theta );
y' = x * sin( theta ) + y * cos ( theta );
```

I need the value of theta. if possible I need to calculate this 1 million times / frame. If thats too much, then with some tweaking(accuracy lost) 1 000 - 50 000 times. Any other solution of the problem appreticiated. Could this be solved mathematically? If not, then is there some(even if inaccurate) way to solve this problem?

Comment: What's "Speed on X and Y axis"? The linear velocity of the particles along these axes?

Comment: Yes.. its how much each particle moves on those axises(its just added to calculate movement)

Comment: How much a particle moves is a distance, not a speed. Do you mean distance or distance per time?

Comment: its in pixel/sec - how much my particle moves on X/Y axis given in pixel/sec. anyways ja72 answered my question exactly, thanks

Comment: If that answered your question exactly, then it seems the "speed on the x and y axis" wasn't actually relevant to the question? It seems that what you were actually asking about was to find the rotation angle about the origin, given the coordinates of a point before and after the rotation -- I don't see any speeds there.

Comment: I didnt know what is needed to calculate it... I put all information I had there

Comment: I see -- apologies for being overly critical. Actually the opposite problem is worse; people sometimes omit information they think isn't relevant but then it turns out that it was, and it takes ages to clarify the incomplete question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from :

$$ x' = x \cos\theta - y \sin\theta $$
 $$ y' = x \sin \theta + y \cos \theta $$

Use this:

$$ \sin\theta = \frac{ y' x - x' y } {x^2+y^2 } $$
 $$ \cos\theta = \frac{ x' x + y' y } {x^2+y^2 } $$

so

$$ \theta = \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{y' x - x' y}{x' x + y' y } \right) $$

To verify the results

$$ x' = x \cos\theta - y \sin\theta = x \left(\frac{ y' x - x' y } {x^2+y^2 }\right) - y \left( \frac{ x' x + y' y } {x^2+y^2 } \right) = $$
 $$  = \frac{x ( x' x+y' y) - y (y' x-x' y) }{x^2+y^2} = \frac{ x' x^2 + x' y^2 }{x^2+y^2}  = x' $$

and similarly for $$ y' = x \sin \theta + y \cos \theta = x \left( \frac{ x' x + y' y } {x^2+y^2 } \right) + y \left(\frac{ y' x - x' y } {x^2+y^2 }\right)  = \ldots = y'$$